# Метод urllib2.urlopen().read() получает ответ по несколько минут

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Разбираюсь с загрузкой данных из ВК через Python. Написал программу, работающую с городом и стеной членов заданной группы (для удобства вырезал всё, не относящееся к моей проблеме). Проблема заключается в том, что через некоторый промежуток времени (всегда разный) программа начинает очень медленно работать, время от времени зависая на несколько минут.

Чтобы понять, в какой момент это происходит, обособил момент с запросом к API строками `'getting wall'` перед и `'got wall'` после. Как я и предполагал, всё виснет именно на `urllib2.urlopen().read()`: получает ответ по несколько минут. При этом через браузер с тем же токеном ответ приходит мгновенно.

Я делаю большую паузу в промежутках между запросами, как уже говорил, виснет каждый раз в разных местах, т.е. при обработке пользователей другой частью программы проблем нет.

```
import urllib2
import json
from time import sleep

access_token = 'kdf4f94fkr9fdefp94frkffkefifj8f5fjefi488940eidf003feijkd03f3'

while True:
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?fields=name,sex,bdate,city,universities&access_token=' + access_token + '&count=1000&offset=0&group_id=15755094'
    members = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    members = json.loads(members)
    sleep(0.5)
    for member in members['response']['users']:

        print member['uid']

        if 'city' in member and member['city'] != 0:
            print 'getting city...'
            city_info = 'https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCitiesById?access_token=' + access_token + '&city_ids=' + str(member['city'])
            city_info = urllib2.urlopen(city_info).read()
            print 'got city'
            city_info = json.loads(city_info)
            sleep(0.5)

        print 'getting wall'
        wall = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?access_token=' + access_token + '&filter=owner&offset=0&count=100&owner_id=' + str(member['uid'])
        wall = urllib2.urlopen(wall).read()
        print 'got wall'
        wall = json.loads(wall)
        sleep(0.5)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня примерно аналогичный код вертится в продакшене уже три года и не тормозит, так что, скорее всего, дело не в нём (но вот в чём, догадок, к сожалению, не имею)

Comment: нужно все логировать, используйте модуль logging вместо print -- позволяет, например, в файлы логировать и смотрите где проблема. Возможно просто с сетью фигня, а может у вк проблемы, например, перегрузка серверов

Answer (score 1):

1. Юзай для удобства vklancer (pypi)
2. Аналогичная проблема, решается только с помощью sleep на 5 сек перед каждым запросом.

Comment: за библиотеку спасибо, воспользуюсь. А в программе идет речь о выгрузке информации о каждом пользователе некоторого сообщества (приходится делать по 3-4 запроса для каждого из примерно 30000 участников), так что столь длинная пауза не вариант, буду дальше искать причину

Answer (score 0):

А не пробовали вместо urllib использовать [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) ?

Comment: Попробовал с requests - тормоза никуда не делись